# Serialization error when calling a MTOM streamed file upload asynchronously

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, exception, asyncfileupload

I'm calling a WCF (non-REST) based asynchronous (async) binary file upload service, which I built using "MTOM" and "Streamed" web.config parameters. The environment is ASP.NET MVC 3, .NET 4, IIS 7.5, VS2010.

The service tries to upload a binary file e.g. zip, pdf or doc. With non-async approach all works fine. But when I'm calling this async service I got this error message on client-side:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:dataStream. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.IO.FileStream' with data contract name 'FileStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Because of the async approach I have to override the WCF constraint concerning streams: either a single param of type Stream or a single param of type MessageContract would be accepted as type within a service method. This approach works fine when working in non-async manner.

To get the whole picture en detail I'm presenting all (relevant) parts of code so far:

**Server:**

Service contract interface, IUploadService:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUploadService
{
   [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
   IAsyncResult BeginUpload(CompletedAsyncUploadResult dataStream, AsyncCallback callback, object state);

   int EndUpload(IAsyncResult result);  
}
```

Container class that wraps the stream and a meta data field, e.g. fileName:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Stream))]   
public class StreamUploadContainer
{
        [DataMember]
        public string fileName;
        [DataMember]    
        public Stream content;   
}
```

IAsyncResult derived class that embeds StreamUploadContainer as Data member:

```
// Simple async result implementation.
public  class CompletedAsyncUploadResult : IAsyncResult
{
    private StreamUploadContainer data;
    public StreamUploadContainer Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    public object AsyncState
    { get { return (object)data; } }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    { get { throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented."); } }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    { get { return true; } }

    public bool IsCompleted
    { get { return true; } }
}
```

Service class UploadService.svc:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)] 
public class UploadService : IUploadService
{
    public IAsyncResult BeginUpload(CompletedAsyncUploadResult dataStream, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string retVal = "All went ok.";
        try
        {
            string docFolderPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, @"App_Data/Scanning/");
            using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(docFolderPath, dataStream.Data.fileName)))
            {
                dataStream.Data.content.CopyTo(outputStream);
            }
            dataStream.Data.content.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            dataStream.Data.content.Close();
            retVal = "Somethin went wrong.";
        }
        CompletedAsyncUploadResult retValContract = new CompletedAsyncUploadResult();
        retValContract.Data = new StreamUploadContainer();
        retValContract.Data.fileName = retVal;
        retValContract.Data.content = Stream.Null;
        return retValContract;
    }

    public int EndUpload(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

WCF service markup file:

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
       <security mode="None">
         <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
       </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfUploadServiceProject.WcfServices.FileStreamUpload.UploadService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehaviour">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfUploadServiceProject.WcfServices.FileStreamUpload.IUploadService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client:**

Calling the service asynchronously

```
private void Upload()
{
    UploadBinaryService.IUploadService client = new UploadBinaryService.UploadServiceClient();
    UploadBinaryService.StreamUploadContainer contract = new UploadBinaryService.StreamUploadContainer();
    contract.content = this.GetStreamSample(@"c:\temp\balloon.zip");
    contract.fileName = "balloon.zip";

    UploadBinaryService.CompletedAsyncUploadResult result = new UploadBinaryService.CompletedAsyncUploadResult();
    result.Data = contract;
    client.BeginUpload(result, FileStreamBinaryUploadAsyncServiceCallback, client);
}

public void FileStreamBinaryUploadAsyncServiceCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var proxy = result.AsyncState as UploadBinaryService.IUploadService;
    if (proxy != null)
    {
        var value = proxy.EndUpload(result);
    }
}
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <endpoint address="http://example.com/WcfServices/FileStreamUpload/UploadService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" contract="UploadBinaryService.IUploadService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUploadService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TPL and [TaskFactory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) method family:

```
TaskFactory.FromAsync(BeginUpload, EndUpload, ...);
           .ContinueWith(result => ...);
```

---

Seems that WCF doesn't supporting serializing of `System.Stream` type. Looks reasonable to me.

Comment: So far I'm implementing the TPL pattern properly within the clients Upload method: var task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginUpload, client.EndUpload, result, client); I got the above mentioned error again within the task.Result InnerException:  There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:dataStream. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.IO.FileStream' with data contract name 'FileStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' is not expected...

Comment: @ProdevMuc: I think you pass an argument which type (`Stream`) can't be serialized by WCF. Can you change it's type?